# Determine whether the relation R on the set A is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, anti-symmetric, or transitive.

Tags: functions, relations

Determine whether the relation R on the set A is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric,
asymmetric, anti-symmetric, or transitive.
(a) A=Z; a R b if and only if a≤ b + 1
(b) A=Z+; a R b if and only if |a − b| ≤ 2
(c) A=Z+ ; a R b if and only if a = b^k for some k ∈ Z+
(d) A=Z; a R b if and only if a + b is even.
(e) A=Z; a R b if and only if |a − b| = 2

Comment: Hi, welcome.  It seems you have just copied and pasted a homework problem into the blank.  Please edit the question to include the work you've done so far and what your confusion is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We proceed as follows:
a)$\alpha\lt{\alpha+1}$, thus R is reflexive. If $\alpha\leq\beta+1$, then obviously if $\beta\leq\alpha+1$,then $\alpha=\beta$, since $\alpha-1\leq\beta\leq\alpha+1$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$.Since the relation only holds in a special case, the relation is anti-symmetric.
b)${aRa}$, since ${|a-a|=0\leq2}$, symmetry follows form the evenness of the absolute value function $(|a-b|=|b-a|=|-(a-b)|)$
c)From b) we infer that the relation is irreflexive, yet symmetrical.